# How do I view sessions in C#

Tags: asp.net, session

code in login page needs code on other page to read session

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = loginService.userLogin(txtusername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
    string user = txtusername.Text;
    if (lblMessage.Text == "Logged In")
    {
        Response.Redirect("AMD.aspx?Name='"+user);
        Session["user"] = txtusername.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("loginPage.aspx");
    }
}
```

code in other page to call session on page 2 so that i can view my session

```
ServiceReferenceUsers.ServicePubsClient serviceObj = new ServiceReferenceUsers.ServicePubsClient();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
    Session["User"] =  lblMessage.Text;
}
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable myData = new DataTable();
    myData = serviceObj.viewUsers();

    GridView1.DataSource = myData;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, But in `btnLogin_Click` you are setting `Session["User"] ` to user name(looks like that) and in `Page_Load` you are overwriting same session with `lblMessage.Text;` And if you want to set the session value to the label try as `lblMessage.Text = Session["User"]`

Comment: You have to set the session variable before you redirect to another page. You also have Session["user"] in both places with different case, i.e. in your btnLogin_click event handler it is Session["user"] and in the Page_Load event it is Session["User"]. Is that intended to have 2 different session-user variables?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Session["User"] =  lblMessage.Text;
```

To

```
lblMessage.Text = Session["User"];
```

On your second page... pilot error? :)